# How to run the same command on multiple servers

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I have 4 suse server working as cluster. name CS-1 CS-2 CS-3 CS-4

On CS-1 can ssh to CS-2 CS-3 CS-4 directly (ssh CS-2, ssh CS-3, ssh CS-4)
On CS-2 can ssh to CS-1 CS-3 CS-4 directly (ssh CS-1, ssh CS-3, ssh CS-4)

I have 3 commands need to execute on all of these 4 servers

```
sed 's/aes128-ctr/aes129-ctr/' </etc/ssh/sshd_config> sshd_config.new; mv sshd_config.new sshd_config
sed 's/aes130-ctr/aes131-ctr/' </etc/ssh/sshd_config> sshd_config.new; mv sshd_config.new sshd_config
sed 's/aes132-ctr/aes133-ctr/' </etc/ssh/sshd_config> sshd_config.new; mv sshd_config.new sshd_config
```

how to do this in one shell script?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this sort of thing.

If this is the sort of thing you're likely to be doing a lot, you might want to look into [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) or other similar automation tooling.

If this is a one-off, probably the most straightforward way is to copy those commands into a script, `scp` the script to the remote machines, and then remotely execute them with `ssh`:

```
$ for host in cs-{2..4}; do scp my-script.sh myuser@"$host":; ssh -t $host "sudo ./my-script.sh"; done
```

As an aside, if you are confident in your `sed` command, rather than manually writing to a temp file and copying the new one in place, you can do something such as:

```
sed --in-place 's/aes128-ctr/aes129-ctr/;s/aes130-ctr/aes131-ctr/;s/aes132-ctr/aes133-ctr/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

As this is one command, you can then simply for each host:

```
$ ssh user@host "sed --in-place 's/aes128-ctr/aes129-ctr/;s/aes130-ctr/aes131-ctr/;s/aes132-ctr/aes133-ctr/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to run same commands on some set of servers quite **often**, I would recommend to look into `pssh` tool and related tools from the same [package](https://www.tecmint.com/execute-commands-on-multiple-linux-servers-using-pssh/).

What I've done on my laptop, from where I need to control ~50 remote hosts (with ssh set up use key authentication already):

1. create list of hostnames like `~/.dev-hosts.list`. This one will just have your list of hostnames

> ```
> dev-host1
> dev-host2
> ...
> ```

2. Use following command to run `date` on each host from that list:

`pssh -h ~/.dev-hosts.list -l developer -i date`

3. *Optional*: wrap it all in an alias for convenience: `alias run.on.dev='pssh -h ~/.dev-hosts.list -l username'`. After that to run `date` on these machines and get output you are just few keystrokes away:

`run.on.dev -i date`

Obviously, you can execute this way practically any command, including your `sed` cases.

Note that `-l` allows you to specify username to ssh to these hosts, and `-i` allows you to see the output your command produces.